# Overcome Excel VBA Americanisation Issues?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a Excel VB Code to enable the user to choose a folder which contains CSVs file, and the macro will insert all the CSV files into the workbook with each worksheet named as the filename of the CSV files. However, there is a date americanisation issues on the date in the worksheet.Some websites suggest that Local:= True can help to correct this issue, but as I am new to Excel VBA, i don't know where to add in this code.Or anyone here have a better suggestion which can help me on this matter? Thank You

```
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If .Show Then myDir = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With
If myDir = "" Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
fn = Dir(myDir & "*.csv")
Do While fn <> ""
    With Workbooks.Open(myDir & fn)
        .Sheets(1).Copy after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
        .Close False
    End With
    fn = Dir
Loop
MsgBox ("All data from your selected source file are completed extracted.")
```

Comment: How is the date displaying, and how do you need it to display?

Comment: In my CSV files, the actual date is 02/01/1987, when the CSVs is imported, the date shows 01/02/1987

Comment: ...and that date is also the name of the folder?  I'm trying to figure out _where_ you need to convert the date.  And is 01 the month or the day?  A better example is: do you need to display "12/13/1987" or "13/12/1987"?

Comment: I think the problem is that when the data within the csv is read in, Excel insists in interpreting the format d/m/y as literally anything else for any date where that interpretation is possible. So it reads 1/12/17 as 12th January but 31/12/17 as 17th Dec 1931. I've had this problem and ended up importing data using FSO.TextStreams, but I've since found this
https://superuser.com/questions/307496/how-can-i-set-excel-to-always-import-all-columns-of-csv-files-as-text  which may help

Answer (score 1):

To *display* a date different on the worksheet, you can change the number format by selecting the cell or cells, and changing the **cell format** by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.  Select a `Date` format that works for you or else choose `Custom` to enter a format like `M/D/YYYY` or `D/M/YYYY` as required.  See: [Format a date the way you want](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e)

To convert the date to **formatted text on a worksheet**, you can use the [`TEXT` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c).  For example (using cell A1):

```
=TEXT(A1, "M/D/YYYY")
```

To use the date as a **formatted string in VBA**, you can use the [`FORMAT` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications).  For example (using cell A1):

```
Format(Range("A1"), "M/D/YYYY")
```

If you need to programmatically change the cell's formatting, you can use the [`NumberFormat` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-numberformat-property-excel):

```
.NumberFormat = "M/D/YYYY"
```

If your worksheet will be used in multiple locales, the [`NumberFormatLocal` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-numberformatlocal-property-excel) might be better:

```
.NumberFormatLocal
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [`Range.NumberFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-numberformat-property-excel) property to display the date how you want.

For example, if your dates are in column "D" then something like:

```
wb.Sheets(i).Range("D:D").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

or you may also use [`Range.NumberFormatLocal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-numberformatlocal-property-excel) if that gives the desired result.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP is trying to display the date different, I think he needs a different value for use with a filename (in which case the number format won't help).